# How to integration test Spring Boot application with multiple configurations

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-test

We currently have a integration test base class

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { MyApp.class, TestConfig.class })
@IntegrationTest({
  "foo:bar",
  "baz:qux"
})
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest {
   ...
}
```

What we'd like to do is add a parameter to `@IntegrationTest` for a single test class. This works quite well when running the tests in separately, but when running all tests, the parameter is not added.

Is there a way around this? E.g., starting a new app for the single test class?

Basically, what I'd like to do is:

```
public class TestOne extends BaseIntegrationTest { ... }

@IntegrationTest({
  "foo:zorblax"
})
public class TestTwo extends BaseIntegrationTest { ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that if you separate the base classes, the application is configured separately.

What I ended up doing:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest {
  // Common methods and fields,
  // @Before, @PostConstruct, etc.
}

@SpringApplicationConfiguration( classes = {...} )
@IntegrationTest({
  "foo:bar",
  "bar:baz"
})
public abstract class WithParamsOne extends BaseIntegrationTest {
  // empty
}

@SpringApplicationConfiguration( classes = { /* Different */ } )
@IntegrationTest({
  "foo:zorblax"
})
public abstract class WithParamsTwo extends BaseIntegrationTest {
  // empty
}

public class ActualTest extends WithParamsOne {
  // @Test
}

public class SecondActualTest extends WithParamsTwo {
  // @Test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use profiles for setting additional properties. They can be activated using the annotation `@ActiveProfiles`. You can also combine profiles in one test.

Based on the previous answer you can create the profiles "param_one" and "param_two". Properties can be set via profile-specific property files: application-param_one.properties and application-param_two.properties

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(...)
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest {
}

@ActiveProfiles("param_one")
public class FirstParamTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {
}

@ActiveProfiles("param_two")
public class SecondParamTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {
}

@ActiveProfiles({ "param_one", "param_two" })
public class AllParamsTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {
}
```

See also the [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties).